# icheck.js radio button automatically gets checked when tabbing (32) through form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, icheck

I am using icheck http://icheck.fronteed.com/ to have fancy radio buttons and check boxes. I am running into an issue though. When I am tabbing through my form and tabbing past the radio button it automatically checks one of the radio buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/75qmj037/7/

This is an example just tab through the form and see how it automatically checks the radio button. Does anyone know how I can change icheck.js so that this does not happen? **I am trying to still be able to tab through the radio buttons but not have it automatically check the first one. I want them to have the same effect as the hover appearance when you tab through just have a ring incase you want to chose them with the spacebar**

I have seen other forums saying this is an issue that is being looked into but this is from a few years ago and cannot find a resolution.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

```
<fieldset class="radio-strip">
    <label class="checked">
      <input name="amt" value="10" type="radio">
      <span class="label-text">$<strong>10</strong></span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input name="amt" value="25" type="radio">
      <span class="label-text">$<strong>25</strong></span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input name="amt" value="50" type="radio">
      <span class="label-text">$<strong>50</strong></span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input name="amt" value="100" type="radio">
      <span class="label-text">$<strong>100</strong></span>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</body>

jQuery('input').iCheck({
  checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
  radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
  increaseArea: '20%' // optional
});
```

But, there is a problem. How do you distinguish on which radio button are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style radio input elements without the need to jQuery or any plugins.

I removed table structure as it was unnecessary HTML and replaced it with div elements.

See this example **(Updated Code)**:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}
.radio {
  border: 1px solid #b3b4b4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 16px;
}
.row:hover .radio {
  border: 2px solid #218996;
}
input[type='radio']:checked + .radio {
  background-color: #218996;
  border: 2px solid #218996;
}
input[type='radio']:checked + .radio::before {
  content: "✓ ";
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size:
}
.row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.row label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.row > label:last-child {
  padding: 12px 0;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form name="titleTypes" id="titleTypes" method="post" action="process.cfm">
  <div>
    <!---Label is here for placement of error message--->
    <label for="rgroup" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <input id="one" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="MV/titleTypeMV.cfm" />
    <label for="one" class='radio' tabindex='1'></label>
    <label for="one">MOTOR VEHICLE / TRAVEL TRAILER TITLE</label>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <input id="two" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="MH/mobileHome.cfm" />
    <label for="two" class='radio' tabindex='1'></label>
    <label for="two">MOBILE HOME</label>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <input id="three" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="BOAT/boat.cfm" />
    <label for="three" class='radio' tabindex='1'></label>
    <label for="three">VESSEL</label>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <input id="four" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="DUPL/duplicate.cfm" />
    <label for="four" class='radio' tabindex='1'></label>
    <label for="four">DUPLICATE</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button class="btn-u" type="submit" name="submit" id="submitBtn" class="submitBtn"><i></i>Next</button>
  </div>
```

This will solve the issue but you have to add tabindex to each element (it could be the same value for all).

Comment: can you show me how to style them the same way i have them in the fiddle? Do you know how to do it that way?

Comment: this is exactly what i need! But can you do it using my table? I have been trying to make it work with my table and dont want to change over 50+ tables if I can. Can you please show me how to just just the radio buttons? So all radio buttons look the same through the entire application? All I need is only the radio button css. But I am unable to make it work using this example

Comment: can you please show me how I can use my table in order to achieve this please. I keep trying to adjust it based on yours but really need to keep the tables. Is there a way to make every radio button no matter its location on the page to just inherit those types of settings and not move its location just replace it?

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex):

> The tabindex global attribute is an integer indicating if the element can take input focus (is focusable), if it should participate to sequential keyboard navigation, and if so, at what position. It can take several values:
>
> a negative value means that the element should be focusable, but should not be reachable via sequential keyboard navigation;

So, you may set the tabindex to -1 for your radio buttons:

The snippet:

```js
jQuery('input').iCheck({
  checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
  radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
  increaseArea: '20%' // optional
});
jQuery('input').attr("tabindex", "-1");
```

```css
.icheckbox_square-blue,
.iradio_square-blue {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icheckbox_square-blue {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.icheckbox_square-blue.hover {
  background-position: -24px 0;
}

.icheckbox_square-blue.checked {
  background-position: -48px 0;
}

.icheckbox_square-blue.disabled {
  background-position: -72px 0;
  cursor: default;
}

.icheckbox_square-blue.checked.disabled {
  background-position: -96px 0;
}

.iradio_square-blue {
  background-position: -120px 0;
}

.iradio_square-blue.hover {
  background-position: -144px 0;
}

.iradio_square-blue.checked {
  background-position: -168px 0;
}

.iradio_square-blue.disabled {
  background-position: -192px 0;
  cursor: default;
}

.iradio_square-blue.checked.disabled {
  background-position: -216px 0;
}


/* HiDPI support */

@media (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
  (min-resolution: 120dpi),
  (min-resolution: 1.25dppx) {
    .icheckbox_square-blue,
    .iradio_square-blue {
      background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
      -webkit-background-size: 240px 24px;
      background-size: 240px 24px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/fronteed/icheck/1.x/icheck.min.js"></script>


<fieldset class="radio-strip">
    <label class="checked">
        <input name="amt" value="10" type="radio">
        <span class="label-text">$<strong>10</strong></span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="amt" value="25" type="radio">
        <span class="label-text">$<strong>25</strong></span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="amt" value="50" type="radio">
        <span class="label-text">$<strong>50</strong></span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="amt" value="100" type="radio">
        <span class="label-text">$<strong>100</strong></span>
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This does not make it checked but it also does not let you tab to the radio buttons either

Comment: I want to be able to tab to it just not check it

Comment: like when you hover to it make that effect when its tabbed to

Comment: @DavidBrierton  I faced with your  problem in depth. In order to solve your issue it is enough to untoggle the checkbox if you navigate with the keyboard. It's enough to save the previous state and..... But, there is a problem. How do you distinguish on which radio button are you? In order to solve this problem it's required to change the label background or something else.... I hope this will help you to investigate more in depth. Thank you so much for sharing your issue.